# What happened to the interesting question about $L_1$ approximation of $x^n$?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Earlier this morning, there was an interesting question on this site about finding the closest approximation to $x^n$ by lower degree polynomials, in the $L^1$ norm on $[0,1]$.

I've figured out how to make *Mathematica* compute the answers almost immediately, and I'm seeing some interesting patterns in the answers, but I can't find the question anymore!

If the original user deleted this in response to the claim that this was in standard textbooks on approximation theory, then I will say that I don't think this is a good reason to delete it. I scanned through some online lecture notes on approximation theory before I started thinking about it, and I could only find the $L_2$ and $L_{\infty}$, not the $L_1$, cases. If experts know where to find this in textbooks, then let them post an explanation of this, but it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: For 10k+ users: the question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97628/). I cast a vote to undelete the question because I am interested in seeing answers to this, too.

Comment: A meta-comment: Moderators can search for deleted questions. However, this would work the best if you can provide some keywords in the original title of the question. I just tried searching for "approximate" and "approximation" and didn't find any that matched your description. It is a good thing that @t.b. remembered it, since questions deleted by the original owner are not listed in the 10K Tools.

Comment: The question is now undeleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer:

The post was deleted by the OP --- presumably in response to a comment suggesting that the result must be in any standard textbook on approximation theory. It is now undeleted by other users.

---

Let me add the following plea to all users asking questions in this site:

> Please do not delete your post immediately if you find out that the answer can be found in Wikipedia/standard textbooks in a particular subject. Such a comment is not necessarily an implicit criticism of the question. Instead I imagine that the commenter only meant to help the OP find a more comprehensive reference for the problem. Thus rather than delete the thread, the OP could request for more focused pointers for references that address the specific question: this would benefit not only the OP but also the future visitors.

A similar remark also holds with regards to deleting a post that happens to be a duplicate of an earlier one.

Comment: Hear hear. Sometimes the trick is to *know* which textbook contains the relevant result. That is one of the many ways Math.SE can be useful.